# Password match verification with SHA-256

Tags: java, sql, authentication, sha256

What I am trying to do is generate the same hashed password at the login and register page. The login page hash must match the register hash inside the data base. I am using java and the following code.

Register page:

```
     // Encrypt password
     try {
        MessageDigest msgDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        msgDigest.reset();
        byte[] passByte = pass.getBytes("UTF-8");
        pass = msgDigest.digest(passByte).toString();
        System.out.println(pass);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(NewCustomer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(NewCustomer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Login page:

```
    // Encrypt password
    try {
        MessageDigest msgDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        msgDigest.reset();
        byte[] passByte = ipwd.getBytes("UTF-8");
        ipwd = msgDigest.digest(passByte).toString();
        System.out.println(ipwd);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(NewCustomer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(NewCustomer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

Comment: Don't call toString() on a byte array. It doesn't return a string representation of the bytes in the array. It returns the type of the array, followed by the hashCode of the array, i.e. useless junk. If you really need a string, encode the byte array with base64 or hex encoding.

Comment: Also, hashing is not encrypting, and although better than storing a plain-text password, this is still way too weak (a simple dictionary attack is sufficient to find passwords). Use BCrypt, or PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256.

Comment: Would using a salt also suffice for protecting it from a dictionary attack?

Comment: The salt should be random. And again, you need something with many rounds, to make an attack much slower than with SHA256. Don't reinvent the wheel. use algorithms designed for that task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out a way to achieve this but it isn't as secure as it could be. I have another file setting the pwd to call the method.

The following code is what I came up with.

```
    public void encryptPass(String pwd) {
            MessageDigest md;
            try {
                md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
                byte[] passBytes = pwd.getBytes();
                md.reset();
                byte[] digested = md.digest(passBytes);
                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
                for (int i = 0; i < digested.length; i++) {
                    sb.append(Integer.toHexString(0xff & digested[i]));
                }
                encryptedPasscode = sb.toString();
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                Logger.getLogger(CryptWithMD5.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
                System.out.println("Error Code: 1002" + e); // Error code for No Algorithm Exception
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can use it for both the login and register page.